# How to compare blob column with string in slick query?

Tags: scala, slick

I have a blob column in my DB. I need to compare this with a string value and filter results using Slick query.

```
Eg:
case class Song( file_sha :Array[Byte])

  class songsTable(tag:Tag) extends Table[Song](tag,"songs"){
    def file_sha = column[Array[Byte]]("file_sha")
    def * = (file_sha) <> (Song.tupled , Song.unapply)}

I am trying something like this:

exec(songsQuery.filter(_.file_sha.asColumnOf[String] === compareString).result)
```

Comment: Which RDMS are you using ?

Comment: Bad practice to compare a String with a Blob. A String is subject of a encoding UTF-16, UTF-8 etc. Reconsider your design.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I changed it as comparing to Array[Byte] itself.